# Any way to tell if an Oracle export is still running?

Tags: oracle, export

I've got an Oracle export that's been running for almost 2 days now.

The export file shows a modification time of 5 am this morning and does not appear to be growing.

The log file does not show any errors.

I think it's stuck and I need to restart it, but I'd hate to cancel it only to find out it was still going and I simply didn't wait long enough.

Any way to definitely know if the export is still running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

select * from v$session where status = 'ACTIVE';

Answer (score 2):

Couple of things:

1) FEEDBACK parameter for export can be helpful to detect activity. I usually set this to 1000 or 10000 records depending on the size of the database I am exporting.

2) You may also be able to take advantage of the v$session_longops to see progress. 
The export program doesn't update LongOps directly, but if there are large tables the table scan progress that is a by product of the export will show up, you should at least see the PercentageDone counting up while large tables are being exported:

```
SELECT ROUND(sofar/totalwork*100,2) as PercentDone, 
       v$session_longops.*
  FROM v$session_longops
 WHERE sofar <> totalwork
 ORDER BY target, sid;
```

-Dave

Answer (score 0):

Method 1:

```
ps -ef|grep expdp
```

Method 2:

Step-1
Find Export JOB using below query.

```
select job_name,owner_name,state from dba_datapump_jobs;
JOB_NAME                       OWNER_NAME           STATE
------------------------------ -------------------- --------------------
SYS_EXPORT_FULL_04             SYSTEM               NOT RUNNING
EXP_TEST_FULL                  SYSTEM               NOT RUNNING
```

Step-2 Then using below query

```
expdp system/password attach=EXP_TEST_FULL
```

Step-3 Kill the job

```
Export> KILL_JOB
```